# Trouble with routing when passing params Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my first question ever on here, so I apologize if I do something wrong.

I have a crud app that i've been working on and for some reason I can not properly route to a specific page/component.  Specifically I have two router links.  One in the sidebar navigation and another within a table that I am trying to pass the .id to.  I have tried implementing this solution:

[https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/986](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LbmQrm?editors=1010)

But honestly, I had it working at some point without having to do the above linked fix.

Here is my current code, please let me know if more information is needed and I would be happy to supply:

router.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import Home from "./views/Home.vue";
import Admin from "./views/Admin.vue";
import Overview from "./views/Overview.vue";
import Products from "./views/Products.vue";
import Requests from "./views/Requests.vue";
import Testing from "./views/Testing.vue";
import BulkTrash from "./views/BulkTrash.vue";
import ViewBulkRequest from "./views/ViewBulkRequest.vue";
import { fb } from "./firebase";

Vue.use(Router);

const router = new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "home",
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: "/admin",
      name: "admin",
      component: Admin,
      meta: { requiresAuth: true },
      children: [
        {
          path: "overview",
          name: "overview",
          component: Overview
        },
        {
          path: "testing",
          name: "testing",
          component: Testing
        },
        {
          path: "bulktrash",
          name: "bulktrash",
          component: BulkTrash
        },
        {
          path: "/view/:bulk_id",
          name: "view-bulk-request",
          component: ViewBulkRequest
        },
        {
          path: "products",
          name: "products",
          component: Products
        },
        {
          path: "requests",
          name: "requests",
          component: Requests
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: "/about",
      name: "about",
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () =>
        import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "./views/About.vue")
    }
  ]
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(x => x.meta.requiresAuth);
  const currentUser = fb.auth().currentUser;

  if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) {
    next("/");
  } else if (requiresAuth && currentUser) {
    next();
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

export default router;
```

And here is the display component code:

BulkTrash.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="bulktrash">
      <div class="container">



          <div class="container-fluid pb-3">

            <h4 class="card-title">New Bulk Trash Request</h4>
<!-- Initalize the Request From -->

            <div class="request-form">

                    <p class="ml-0 mt-5 mb-3">Pickup Information</p>

                <!-- Bulk Trash User Input Boxes -->

                <select v-model="bulk.bulk_type" class="form-control mb-2" required>
                        <option disabled value="">Type of bulk trash</option>
                        <option>Metal</option>
                        <option>E-waste</option>
                        <option>Cardboard</option>
                </select>

                <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Address (location for pickup)"
                    v-model="bulk.bulk_location" required>
                <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Zone (leave blank if unsure)"
                    v-model="bulk.bulk_zone">                    

                    <p class="ml-0 mt-4 mb-3">Contact information</p>

                <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Name (resident name)"
                    v-model="bulk.bulk_requestor">
                <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Phone"
                    v-model="bulk.bulk_phone">
                <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Email"
                    v-model="bulk.bulk_email">

                    <p class="ml-0 mt-4 mb-3">Additional information</p>

                <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Item description (chair, washing machine, computer, etc.)"
                    v-model="bulk.bulk_description">
                <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Notes for drivers (pet's, gates, hazards, etc.)"
                    v-model="bulk.bulk_dnotes">

                <button class="btn btn-success mt-2 mb-5"
                @click="saveData">
                Save</button>
                <button class="btn btn-secondary mt-2 mb-5 ml-1"
                @click="cancelRequest">
                Cancel</button>

            </div>

<!-- Start of Request Table -->

            <div class="container h-100 pt-3"> 

              <h4>Bulk Requests</h4>


              <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Type</th>
                    <th scope="col">Location</th>
                    <th scope="col">Zone</th>
                    <th scope="col">Item Desc.</th>
                    <th scope="col">Notes</th>
                    <th scope="col">Requestor</th>
                    <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                  <tr v-for="bulk in bulks" :key="bulk.id">
                    <td> {{bulk.id}} </td>
                    <td> {{bulk.type}} </td>
                    <td> {{bulk.location}} </td>
                    <td> {{bulk.zone}} </td>
                    <td> {{bulk.description}} </td>
                    <td> {{bulk.dnotes}} </td>
                    <td> {{bulk.requestor}} </td>
                    <td> {{bulk.phone}} </td>
                    <td> {{bulk.email}} </td>
                    <td> 

                        <router-link  class="secondary-content"
                        v-bind:to="{name: 'view-bulk-request', params: {bulk_id: bulk.bulk_id}}">
                        <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                        </router-link> 

                    </td>
                    <!-- <td> {{bulk.requested}} </td> -->
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>           
        </div>          
      </div> 
  </div>   

</template>

<script>
import {fb, db} from '../firebase'

export default {
  name: "BulkTrash",
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      bulks: [],
      bulk: {
        bulk_id:null,
        bulk_type:null,
        bulk_location:null,
        bulk_zone: null,
        bulk_description: null,
        bulk_dnotes: null,
        bulk_requestor: null,
        bulk_phone: null,
        bulk_email: null,
        //bulk_requested: null,
      },
        selected: '',
        selected2: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    readData() {

        db.collection('bulktrash').orderBy('bulk_type').get().then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                console.log(doc.data());
                const data = {
                    'id': doc.id,
                    'bulk_id': doc.data().bulk_id,
                    'type': doc.data().bulk_type,
                    'location': doc.data().bulk_location,
                    'zone': doc.data().bulk_zone,
                    'description': doc.data().bulk_description,
                    'dnotes': doc.data().bulk_dnotes,
                    'requestor': doc.data().bulk_requestor,
                    'phone': doc.data().bulk_phone,
                    'email': doc.data().bulk_email
                    //'requested': doc.data().bulk_requested
                }
                this.bulks.push(data)
        })
      })
    },
    cancelRequest() {
        console.log("Cancel funciton working")
    },
    saveData() {
      db.collection("bulktrash").add(this.bulk)
      .then((docRef) => {
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id)
        Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data.apply(this))
        this.readData()
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("error adding document: ", error)
      })

      },
      reset() {
        //Object.assign(this.$data, this.$options.data.apply(this))
      }
    },  
    created() {
      this.readData() 
    }

  };

</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped lang="scss">
</style>
```

Thank you to anyone that is willing to give this a glance.

Comment: the codepen looks to be working ok, whats wrong with it

Comment: Please be more concrete, what is not working, are there any errors in your console? Did you already try to debug you code, what were you findings? Or create your own codepen so people could watch themselves

Comment: I did not know I could create my own codepen, thank you for the info!  I did fix my issue.  Embarrassing to say but I was just missing an 's'. :X  I've now moved onto a new issue where I have user auth setup through Firebase.  I can create (register) new users and login current user.  However, I noticed that when I create a new user, then if I login with that user from another browser or machine, the two users seem to be bound to the same session.  Meaning that if one users changes anything while logged in, the other user's info changes to that of the user who committed the action. I'll post.